# After langiage switching, language doesn't switch to default keyboard layout in another application

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I have a problem with language keyboard layout in Windows 10. 
After switching to another language than default and changing application, language doesn't switch to default keyboard layout.
OS: Windows 10 professional x64.
I have installed English-US, Serbian (Latin) and Serbian (Cyrillic) in that order.
Default input metod - English-US.

Answer (score 1):

go to Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings then
switching input methods and enable chekbox let me set a different input method for each app window and save